# ActiveRecord Saving Association Automatically Leading To Infinite Loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following two models:

```
class Inquiry < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :offer

  around_save :check_status

  def check_status
    status_changed = self.status_changed?

    yield

    if status_changed
      .
      .
      .
    end
  end
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inquiry

  around_save :check_status

  def check_status
    status_changed = self.status_changed?

    yield

    if self.inquiry && status_changed
      status = ...
      self.inquiry.update_attribute('status', status)
    end
  end
end
```

Not every offer necessarily belongs to an inquiry, but when I try saving an offer that does, a loop is triggered where the offer `check_status` tries to update the status of the inquiry, and for some reason the `yield` in the inquiry `check_status` attempts to autosave the offer, which triggers the inquiry status update again, resulting in a `stack level too deep` error.

I tried adding `autosave: false` after `has_one :offer` but it didn't work. Any ideas what could be causing this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: if always the `inquery.status` depends on the `offer.status`, just delegate it. If not, I think you've a problem in your design. You said Not every offer necesiraly has an inquery, while in your code you say `offer belongs_to inquery`.

Comment: And what does the statement `status_changed = self.status_changed?` in Offer check_status means. I think this also my be a problem. You can check `if self.inquery` should be `if status_changed && self.inquery` .

Comment: And the last question, why you use `around_save` anyway????

Comment: The inquiry status doesn't always depend on that of the offer, but I'm using a `belongs_to` because I want an association between them. I corrected the code you mentioned in your second comment, I actually check if the status was changed but it slipped somehow while I was pasting the code. And I'm using `around_save` because I want to check if there was a change in the status and I want it to work on create and update.

Comment: I think that the `belongs_to` should go the other way. `inquery belongs_to offer`, this way when you save the inquery, it will not trigger the save on the offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone runs into a similar issue in the future, I ended up changing the model ownership direction like Nafaa suggested and it solved the problem.